# Show following IVP has solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

> Show that the solution $y(t)$ of the given initial value problem exists on the specified
>   interval. $$a) y'=y^2+\cos t^2 , y(0)=0; t\in [0,1/2]$$ $$(b) y'=(4y+e^{-t^2})e^{2y},y(0)=0; t\in[0,1/8\sqrt{e}]$$

So in first case I considered a rectangle R with one of the side as $[0,1/2]$ then I can apply Peano's theorem to that rectangle to conclude that there's a solution to IVP and I did the same for the second one. But these solution will exists on some sub-rectangle how do I show solution exists on whole given interval?